# Hadoop: Number of reducer is not equal to what I have set in program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have set mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum to 10 in `mapred-site.xml`, and I also write `jobConf.setNumReduceTasks(5)` in my job.

Everything is ok if I run the job in Shell.

But when I run the same job by eclipse, only one reducer was launched.

I try to edit Map/Reduce Locations in eclipse, and set `mapred.reduce.tasks` to 10. But that still doesn't work.

Is there any other parameters I can adjust in eclipse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Running it in eclipse seems to use the local job runner. It only supports 0 or 1 reducers. If you try to set it to use more than one reducer, it ignores it and just uses one anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Problem was solved. In eclipse, `LocalJobRunner` will be lanuched by default, which can only start one reducer. But we can do something to run the job on the claster. Here is my reference: [Analytics for Hadoop Job Submission](http://www.cnblogs.com/xuxm2007/archive/2011/09/09/2172644.html). I'm sorry the website is in Chinese. But I hope it can be useful for others.