# number of map and reduce task does not change in M/R program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, task

I have a question.. I have a mapreduce program that get input from cassandra. my input is a little big, about 100000000 data. my problem is that my program takes too long to process, but I think mapreduce is good and fast for large volume of data. so I think maybe I have problems in number of map and reduce tasks.. I set the number of map and reduce asks with JobConf, with Job, and also in conf/mapred-site.xml, but I don't see any changes.. in my logs at first there is map 0% reduce 0% and after about 2 hours working it shows map 1% reduce 0%..!!
what should I do? please Help me I really get confused...

Comment: give us some more details, it's hard to help without this much information.

Comment: I want to process a large volume of data with mapreduce.may data are 100000000 and for example I want to calculate the average of these data. but it takes too long to process.. I want to know if I can run this process very fast by mapreduce. and if I can increase the number of map and reduce tasks to do the process faster. in bellow link I read this may be from eclipse. do you have any idea about this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298659/hadoop-and-number-of-reducers-in-eclipse

Comment: also this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928101/hadoop-number-of-reducer-is-not-equal-to-what-i-have-set-in-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider these points to check where the bottleneck might be --

1. Merely configuring to increase the number of map or reduce tasks files won't do. You need hardware to support that. Hadoop is fast, but to process a huge file, as you have mentioned
   you need to have more numbers of parellel map and reduce tasks
   running. To achieve what you need more processors. To get more
   processors you need more machines (nodes). For example, if you have
   2 machines with 8 processors each, you get a total processing power
   of around 16. So, total 16 map and reduce tasks can run in parallel and the next set of tasks comes in as soon as slots gets unoccupied out of the 16 slots you have.
   Now, when you add one more machine with 8 processors, you now have 24.
2. The Algorithms you used for map and reduce. Even though, you have
   processing power, that doesn't mean your Hadoop application will
   perform unless your algorithm performs. It might be the case that
   a single map task takes forever to complete.

Comment: so you mean it depends in what my hardware is? well I have only two processors, so you mean I have only 2 map and reduce?

Comment: I read somewhere that this because of eclipse. it runs the program in a local mode. do you know any thing about this? here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298659/hadoop-and-number-of-reducers-in-eclipse

Comment: and also this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928101/hadoop-number-of-reducer-is-not-equal-to-what-i-have-set-in-program

Comment: With respect to your first comment, if you have 2 processor (unless they are Hyper Threading enabled, where you can have 4 tasks running in parallel), you'll have probably 1 map and 1 reduce task running at a given time, unless you use some lazy initialization of reducers to actually have 2 map task running with 2 processors. Try adding more machines and create a cluster to get the difference. With more machine more tasks, more parallelism and more speed. You are processing a 100 Million, records, which might be too large for a cluster of only 2 processors, for you to actually see a speed up.

Comment: With respect you your 2nd comment, in a real cluster environment, I would suggest you to use the command line instead of eclipse, so that your mapreduce jar can be easily distributed across the cluster nodes by Hadoop, without any of your effort. Eclipse like IDE should probably be only used for developing the MapReduce job, and testing if your map/reduce logic work in a small set of data.